Problem with chrome web browsers and Django sign in
I have a problem that I can't get my head around. I guess that an answer is out there....
I have deployed an Django app. In local server (development) the user can regardless of browser sign in to the Django app. Now when I have deployed the app using AWS Lightsail, Nginx, and Gunicorn. I experience an issue with the Chrome browser. When user after "signed in" is redirected to the home page. The user get "signed out" from Django.
I have logged (using print(self.request.user)) the sign in process and can see that the user/password is accepted and that the self.request.user is "signed in". But when the user is redirected, the self.request.user is None.
What I have a hard time understanding is that the same Chrome browser window works with the local server but not on the deployed server. Gunicorn worker doesn't logg out so it shouldn't be a memory issue?
I've been looking for similar questions, perhaps someone can direct me to them. Any coding that needs to be shared?

This is a Cookies storage issue. Without more info we can’t debug. I am inclined to believe that you uncovered a bug in Chromium but that is most unlikely. If there is more info you can share, please do.

One reason can be multiple worker process of gunicorn.
This can happen if SECRET_KEY is dynamic and gunicorn run on multiple worker, login doesn't work properly.
To Test:
keep the worker process in gunicorn to 1. and try again if the issue is solved.
one more reason can be SESSION_COOKIE_PATH, it should match with your domain.check that too.
